# Safari PDF controls missing PDF is rendered in iFrame

Tags: pdf, iframe, safari

Anyone know why the PDF controls normally available when displaying a PDF in Safari would be missing when displayed in an `iframe`? Neither the "hover" controls or the extnded contextual menu is available. Safari reognized it as a PDF because the contextual menu includes the word PDF in the Open commands, ie. "Open PDF in new Window"

Opening a PDF into an empty browser works fine. The built in controls in Chrome and Firefox are there as well and work fine.

I am serving the PDFs using a very simple web page with an `iframe` inside a `div`.

I could be wrong but thought that they were there when I first started this project but I just noticed today that they are missing. Without them, PDF drawings cannot be zoomed in and out rendering them useless as PDFs.

Comment: Not sure as to why that would make a difference - but you might find it useful to load your PDF using JavaScript. Take a look [at this generator](http://www.pdfobject.com/generator.php) for some idea of what you can control.

Comment: I tried embedding in a div, but found that using an iFrame works better for me in all the browsers except for Safari. Safari was working ok until now.

Comment: Better how? The site I referenced seems to suggest you should use either a object (presumably in a div) or the JS approach. I should imagine an `<iframe>` is _not_ recommended.

Comment: I know that part of the problme dealt with iOS. In response to your question, however, I just now tried to embed the pdfs in a div. I cannot get it to work. The div remains blank. The PDFs are not being displayed until a tree menu leaf is clicked. The PDF is then displayed next to the menu. To test your suggestion, in my default.html I changed the iframe to a  div with class='pdfdiv' and changed the jQuery onclick function for the leaf to  var myPDF = new PDFObject({url:'http://xxx.xx.xxx/myDocument.pdf'}).embed('.pdfdiv'); which works in the iFrame.

Comment: ^ And did it load without any errors in your JS console? (I hope you also loaded the PDFObject.js library ([from here](http://www.pdfobject.com/downloads/index.php))!

Comment: I'm loading pdfobject.min.js. Sorry I should have checked the JS console. You are right the myPDF var is showing myPDF:false after making the call. What does that mean?

Comment: Maybe `embed()` only takes an `id`, rather than a `class`? (If you use the generator, it doesn't use a # to denote an `id`, so I imagine a dot cannot be used as a `class` indicator either).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13535/discussion-between-user278859-and-halfer)